# How to get the record from a query in VBA Acces?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

Considering this excel

[image]

I made a VBA function in Microsoft Access to read this file and Save/Import it on my tables namely: Deparments, Employees, and Positions. This is how I made my function:

```
Private Sub Command41_Click()
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim intLine As Long
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim sql As String, deptId As Long, empId As Long, jobId As Long
    
    fileName = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Reports.xlsx"
    
    If fso.FileExists(fileName) Then
        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = True
        
        Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
        Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets(1)
        
        intLine = xlWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To intLine
            sql = "SELECT ID FROM Departments WHERE DeptName = " & xlWs.Cells(i, 1)
            Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot)
            MsgBox rs
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is that this line `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot)` is returning this error: **Error 3061 Too few parameters. Expected 4**. I don't know what are the other parameters that I am missing since in the net I only found two.

**Any help is much appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

DeptName is a text type field. Concatenated parameters for text field require apostrophe delimiters.

`sql = "SELECT ID FROM Departments WHERE DeptName = '" & xlWs.Cells(i, 1) & "'"`

Instead of VBA opening Excel objects, an alternative is to set a link to Excel sheet and treat the link as a table (except cannot edit its data). Use the link in queries that join tables or use DLookup() aggregate function.

`MsgBox rs` will also fail because rs is a recordset object and MsgBox expects a string. Can read a field of recordset: `MsgBox rs!ID`. If multiple ID values are retrieved, have to loop through recordset to build a string with concatenation. With Excel link alternative, could just open a filtered query object.